# Could insert statements match data from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to do an insert on a table from another table with matched values and IDs.

lets say on table1 there are values of names and IDS. Like John and 55.

I am trying to only insert the 55 into table2 since John is already on table2 but just missing his ID.
I know I can do update statement to update the value for John to 55, but my tables have over 3000 values, and it will be hard to do one at a time:

Anyway I can write a query to enter a value into the other table as long as the names match together?

what I tried so far:

```
insert into desired_table (id,version,source_id,description,r_id) 
SELECT HI_SEQUENCE.nextval,'0', select min (id) 
from table
where name in (select name from table2 where table2_name is not null), 
table2_name, 
table2.r_id from table2 where name is not null;
```

Issue with this statement is it inserts multiple values, but it only inserts it into where the min ID is.

Anyway I can adjust this and have it pull more than one ID?

Comment: Needs:  Sample data, DDL code to create the tables, example of desired output.  Also, what have you tried and what is wrong with that?

Comment: As a last resort you may use scalar subquery as a new value

Comment: insert into desired_table (id,version,source_id,description,r_id) SELECT HI_SEQUENCE.nextval,'0', select min (id) from table where name in (select name from table2 where table2_name is not null), table2_name, table2.r_id from table2 where name is not null;

Answer (score 2):

Use Merge statement (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
Merge into Table1 d
Using Table 2 s
on d.name=s.name
when matching then update
age=s.age
when not matching then insert
(col1, col2)
values (s.col1, s.col2);
```

Comment: This is very helpful, but I think it would work on update statements. Any hint on insert statements?

Comment: Well, yes - that should work, but - as the question is tagged as **Oracle**, posting a link to MS SQL Server documentation is a little bit *doubtful*. Lucky you, syntax is just the same here.

Comment: I am not fimiliar with merge statements, what I tried was the following, but the issue is that it is inserting everything in one place where that min id is located. Anyway I can have it pull more than 1 ID and insert to them?


insert into desired_table (id,version,source_id,description,r_id) SELECT HI_SEQUENCE.nextval,'0', select min (id) from table where name in
(select name from table2 where table2_name is not null), table2_name, table2.r_id from table2 where name is not null;

Comment: there are bad and worse approaches (in my mind) to achieve your req, but the sequence itself gives you  new value upon calling each time. keeping that in mind, 1. can be done via loop (worse approach) 2. have a rowid during insert to add it to nextval in seq and update seq to appropriately so it does not overlap with already inserted values (bad approach?).

Comment: @Littlefoot- thank you for pointing out; looks like the question tags more than 1 db sys.

Answer (score 0):

You might want a trigger to automate the above task.

```
   Create Trigger sample after insert on
   Table1 for each row
  Begin
  Update table2 set table2.age = :NEW.AGE where
  table2.id=:NEW.Id
  END;
```

Comment: Thank you, I am not sure they would like an automatic trigger though.

Answer (score 0):

Got this working by generating insert statements and running them with insert all